# Stopping Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am new to winforms programming and I am starting to work with threads.

I have managed to start a thread, but now I want to be able to click on a cancel button to stop the thread.

Here is my code so far...

This starts the thread:

```
private void btnSessions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread downloadThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DownloadThread));
    downloadThread.Start();
}
```

This is the thread:

```
void DownloadThread()
{
     // Do the work
}
```

This is the button I want to use to cancel the thread:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Stop the thread
}
```

Can anyone help me work out what I need to put in btnCancel_Click please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) for this, which supports a natural way of canceling tasks:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource2;
private CancellationToken _token;

private void btnSessions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _token = _tokenSource2.Token;

    Task task = Task.Run(() => DownloadThread(), _token);
}

private void DownloadThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //do work

        //cancel if needed
        if (_token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Stop the thread
    _tokenSource2.Cancel();
}
```

More about canceling tasks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx

Why you should *not* use `Thread.Abort`: [What's wrong with using Thread.Abort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort)

Comment: sorry if I am being stupid but its saying "The name 'tokenSource2' does not exist in the current context" - I cannot work out where I should put the var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource(); in the code :(

Comment: @TrevorDaniel I've updated my answer. If you can't grasp the concepts of field declaration and variable scopes, you should probably go through some basic C# (or any other language) tutorials, before trying to write multi-threaded applications.

Comment: You can use a `CancellationToken` even with an explicit `Thread`, you don't *need* to use it with a `Task`.  Also, there's no point in checking if cancellation is requested before calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.  The *point* of `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is that it only throws if cancellation is requested, and it does nothing otherwise.  `IsCancellationRequested` exists so that you can do something *other than throwing an exception* if cancellation is requested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the downloadThread a field in your object:

```
Thread downloadThread; 
private void btnSessions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     downloadThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DownloadThread));
     downloadThread.Start();
}

void DownloadThread()
{
     // Do the work
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     downloadThread.Abort();
}
```

A background worker would be a better solution for ui related processing.

Comment: [Thread.Abort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is evil: it is not determined where the thread execution will be terminated. So, the **resources** acquired by the thread **might not be disposed**. Please avoid calling `Thread.Abort()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It's better don't use `Thread` and especially `Thread.Abort` for task like this. C# has high abstract wrapper to hide threads. Just use `Task` and `CancellationToken`.
Here is example:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // define in class
CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

private void btnSessions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DownloadThread(), ct ); // start task
}

private void DownloadThread()
{
    // You need to check this at some point where cancel may occur
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cancelToken.Cancel(false); // cancel task
}
```

More information can be found at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)